# fish shell how to tokenize variable to a list

Tags: shell, fish, nautilus

It's weird that others are complaining that fish is always splitting their variables to lists. But to me it's just having the multiline variable as a single string.

I'm trying to write a nautilus script. The nautilus should set a variable called `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` with the selected files separated with newlines.

I'm trying to get them as a list to loop over them with fish. But they just behave as a single element.

```
set -l files $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS

for i in (seq (count $files))
   echo (count $files) >> koko
end
```

and the file koko now shows the number 1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fish does not split variables after they have been set (this is known as "word splitting").

What it does, however, do is split command substitutions on newlines, so

```
set files (echo $files)
```

will work.

Or, if you wish to make it clear that you're doing this to split it, you can use `string split` like

```
set files (string split \n -- $files)
```

which will then end up the same (because currently `string split` only adds newlines), but looks a bit clearer. (The "--" is the option separator, so nothing in $files is interpreted as an option)

The latter requires fish >= 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split variable by space, then the command is:

```
set files (string split ' ' --no-empty -- $files)
```

Do not forget `--no-empty`.

Now you can also get individuals values by, for example:

```
if set -q files[1]
    echo files[1] $files[1]
end

if set -q files[2]
    echo files[2] $files[2]
end

...
```